# What exactly is MyClassName.class in Java

Tags: java

What exactly is the meaning of the following construction: `MyClassName.class` ?

At first I thought `MyClassName.class` would represent the access of a static class variable defined for `MyClassName` class, but it that'd be true then the following  assignment should be possible:

```
MyClassName m = new MyClassName();
Class<MyClassName> clazz = m.class; //access static class variable by using an instance variable
```

What is the true meaning of `MyClassName.class`? Is it a static class variable? is it a Java special construction?

Comment: check that out: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html

Answer (score 1):

Every class in Java has an associated instance of java.lang.Class which contains metadata about the class i.e its attributes, types, methods, super class etc.

Here MyClassName.class is called **class literal**. Link to Java doc for further info - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.8.2